# Have a recursive CTE, tree path not populating

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have the following SQL, which returns the correct hierarchy. The only problem is it does not populate the "treepath" column. The column remains NULL for all rows but should hold names for all levels at 1 or higher.

```
WITH DirectReportsCTE (mgrid, EmpID, ename, mgrname, Lvl, treepath)
AS
(
-- Anchor member definition
    SELECT mgrid, EmpID, ename, mgrname, 0 AS Lvl, CAST(mgrname AS VARCHAR(1024)) AS treepath
    FROM #tmpPeople
    WHERE MgrID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition
    SELECT p.mgrid, p.EmpID, p.ename, p.mgrname, Lvl + 1, 
       CAST(rtrim(d.treepath) + ' -> ' + CAST(p.mgrname AS VARCHAR(1024)) AS VARCHAR(1024)) AS treepath
    FROM #tmpPeople AS p
    inner JOIN DirectReportsCTE AS d
        ON p.MgrID = d.EmpID
)
-- Statement that executes the CTE
insert into #tmpSupers (MgrID, EmpID, ename, mgrname, treepath, Lvl)
(
SELECT MgrID, EmpID, ename, mgrname, treepath, Lvl
FROM DirectReportsCTE dr
)
GO
```

These are the fields in the table (#tmpPeople) I'm querying from:
empid, ename, mgrid, mgrname

What am I missing on the "treepath" and it not populating?

Answer (score 2):

I think that in your anchor part the `mgrname` is NULL too (there is no manager).

Not absolutely sure, but I think you've to change this

```
CAST(mgrname AS VARCHAR(1024))
```

to

```
CAST('' AS VARCHAR(1024))
```

The reason: Concatenating a NULL with a string value will be a NULL finally. Try this:

```
SELECT 'This' + ' ' + 'works';
SELECT 'This' + NULL + 'not';
```

HoneyBadger pointed to the [`CONCAT()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql), which works great, even with `NULL` and you do not need to cast everything to a string type before:

```
SELECT CONCAT('This', NULL, ' ', 'works (type tolerant):', 100, '/', GETDATE());
```

returns (date format depending on settings!)

```
This works (type tolerant):100/Feb 22 2018  9:56PM
```

But this needs SQL Server 2012+

Comment: Pretty sure you're right. Alternatively, you can use the `concat` function, it takes care of nulls itself.

Comment: @HoneyBadger True, thx! But this requires SQL Server 2012+... I'll add this to the answer